# Better verbage than "Most Recent"

Tags: terminology, programming

I have a report that is creating a list of customer visits, with the goal of breaking customers into "Active, With Future Appointments", "Active, Recently", "Recent, No-Show", "Not seen in 90 days", etc.

Given a list of customers, I'm listing the "Most recent" visits. But that includes scheduled/future appointments. "Max", "Top", "Current"... doesn't seem to fit either. The terms just seem — if I'm considering a conversational tone — off.

Is there a word/phrase that would capture the prominent, highest visit in common English? (not database/programming languages, since "Max Visit" just doesn't sound right in documentation to the non-programming layperson).

Edit: Looking at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61860/analogue-of-most-recent-for-events-in-the-future), and I don't see anything that seems to sound easy on the ears either. Soonest? Immenent? Impending? "Most Recent or Impending Visit"? Doesn't seem to condense "max visit" into English with sounding weird to me...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *[latest](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/latest)*

> most recent, or newest

Answer (score 2):

I would say, simply "Recent/Scheduled Visits".   I can't think of a singular adjective that describes both recent and pending ones.

Answer (score 0):

How about cutting it to the basic and saying 'Most'. This suggests to me most, latest, most visits, etc, in one short-hand way. Perhaps you're over-thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use "proximate", which may refer to both recent past and near future, but it may sound too fancy to your coworkers. I post part of the OED entry, below. You'll see that the proposed usage isn't exactly in line with the examples.

> a. Coming immediately before or after in a chain of causation, agency, reasoning, or other relation; immediate, short-term. Freq. in proximate cause. Opposed to remote or ultimate.
>
> **1641**   `Ld. Digby Speeches in Parl. 16`   Wicked Ministers have bin the proximate causes of our miseries.
>   **1661**   `J. Glanvill Vanity of Dogmatizing xii. 114`   We hastily conclude that impossible, which we see not in the proximate capacity of its Efficient.
>   **1713**   `R. Nelson Life Dr. George Bull xxxiii. 190`   Whether one call this Power the remote and fundamental, or the proximate Power of Free-will.
>   **1771**   `T. Smollett Humphry Clinker I. 127`   The proximate cause of her breach with Sir Ulic Mackilligut.
>   **1792**   `G. Crabbe Let. 5 Sept. in Sel. Lett. & Jrnls. (1985) i. 45`   The discovery of the cause (the proximate cause) of muscular motion which has so long puzzled physiologists, is an important communication.
>   **1825**   `Lancet 10 Dec. 373/1`   The proximate cause of cholic is said to be spasm of the intestine.
>   1881   `B. F. Westcott & F. J. A. Hort New Test. in Orig. Greek II. Introd. iii. 219`   Readings that are explicable by the supposition of a common proximate original.
>   **1927**   `Jrnl. Amer. Chem. Soc. 49 3061`   Our work indicates that the proximate cause of superacidity in a solution is an abnormally high value of the hydrogen-ion activity.
>   **1969**   `Jrnl. Biol. Chem. 244 4075/2`   Present evidence does not favor 3-hydroxyuric acid as a proximate oncogen.
>   **2002**  `Econ. & Polit. Weekly 20 Apr. 1525/3`   The proximate trigger was the Gulf war in the second half of 1990–91, which jacked up international oil prices.